# Getting ROLLUP Total With HAVING Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this SQL logic for a mapper function that will help a grid display information about the number of people who have completed each training at each location.

I'm having issues with trying to get the number of rows returned after filtering using a HAVING clause. I believe that this is due to WITH ROLLUP being run before HAVING, but I can't figure out how to work around that.

MY SQL:

```
SELECT l.name AS Name, COUNT(IF(tst.id = 1, 1, NULL)) AS Training_1, COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS count 
FROM location_entity AS l
LEFT JOIN location_user AS lu 
    ON l.id = lu.location_entity_id
LEFT JOIN user_entity AS u 
    ON u.id = lu.user_entity_id
LEFT JOIN user_role AS r 
    ON r.id = u.user_role_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ts.user_entity_id, ts.user_training_session_type_id 
        FROM user_training_session ts 
        GROUP BY ts.user_entity_id, ts.user_training_session_type_id
    ) AS ts 
    ON ts.user_entity_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN user_training_session_type AS tst 
    ON ts.user_training_session_type_id = tst.id 
GROUP BY l.name 
    WITH ROLLUP
HAVING (Training_1 >= 1)
```

CURRENT RESULT:

```
+------------+------------+-------+
|    Name    | Training_1 | count |
+------------+------------+-------+
| Location_1 |          1 |     1 |
| Location_2 |          2 |     1 |
|            |          5 |    10 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
+------------+------------+-------+
|    Name    | Training_1 | count |
+------------+------------+-------+
| Location_1 |          1 |     1 |
| Location_2 |          2 |     1 |
|            |          3 |     2 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

**Edit:** 
1. Re-wrote the SQL using just left joins. Will add a script for creating tables and inserting data later today.

Comment: Subquery / CTE.

Comment: Yuck!  You are mixing `left join` and `right join`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT ...
...
GROUP BY l.name, (tst.id = 1)
    WITH ROLLUP
HAVING (Training_1 >= 1)
```